# In a Smart-Table (http://ngmodules.org/modules/Smart-Table) how do you access removeDataRow functionality

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm pretty new to Angular and Smart-Table (http://ngmodules.org/modules/Smart-Table) and I am trying to add the remove functionality for a table row.  There is a built-in function (removeDataRow) but unlike it's nearby cousin, updateDataRow, I haven't been able to figure out how to trigger it.  Here is the relevant code so far:

deleteAction.html:

```
<button custom ng-click="doAction()"
    class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
        Delete
</button>
```

Table column definition:

```
$scope.columnCollectionDispo = [
        {label: 'ID', map: 'dispositionId', isEditable: false},
        {label: 'Name', map: 'name', isEditable: true},
        {label: 'Code', map: 'code', isEditable: true},
        {label: 'Description', map: 'description', isEditable: true},
        {label: 'Sort Index', map: 'sortIndex', isEditable: true, type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Status', map: 'status'},
        {label:'actions', cellTemplateUrl:'../views/admin/deleteAction.html'}

    ];
```

Table Global Config:

```
        $scope.globalConfig = {
        isPaginationEnabled: true,
        itemsByPage: 5,
        maxSize: 10,
        selectionMode: 'single',
        doAction: function(){
            $scope.$emit('deleteAction');
        }
    };
```

Delete method:

```
 $scope.$on('deleteAction',function(){
        alert("Delete List"); //just to see if I am reaching this code

    });
```

Table display:

```
<smart-table class="table table-striped" table-title="DispoElements"
             config="globalConfig" rows=dispoElements columns="columnCollectionDispo">
</smart-table>
```

I can get the Delete button displayed and spent some cycle time on trying to trigger the removeDataRow method.  Failing that, I have been trying to figure out how to pass the table element id back to execute a delete.  I would rather use the built-in function.  Any ideas?  TIA,
    Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is you cannot.  I switched from smart-table to trNgGrid and it seems to be working much better.  Have display, edit, and delete working fine.  Working on Add.  So far the add works, but I want the grid to go to the newly added record and place it in edit mode, but no good on that as yet.  Still a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 2):

Since the smart table directive used isolates its scope with parent controller, you cannot directly access your function defined in parent controller.

To access the same,you can use `$parent` attribute

Try this in `deleteAction.html`,

```
<button ng-click="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.doDelete(dataRow)"
    class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
        Delete
</button>
```

Table column definition,

```
$scope.columnCollectionDispo = [
        {label: 'ID', map: 'dispositionId', isEditable: false},
        {label: 'Name', map: 'name', isEditable: true},
        {label: 'Code', map: 'code', isEditable: true},
        {label: 'Description', map: 'description', isEditable: true},
        {label: 'Sort Index', map: 'sortIndex', isEditable: true, type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Status', map: 'status'},
        {label:'actions', cellTemplateUrl:'../views/admin/deleteAction.html'}

    ];
```

In your parent controller,

```
$scope.doDelete=funcion(dataRow){

alert('inside doDelete');

//implement the code for delete action

}
```

Here is the plunker working demo,

http://plnkr.co/edit/87yfJQEbBjzOlJoCZ3aq?p=preview

Comment: Very promising, but I think I am missing something.  In the Plunker, your index is always 2?  I dropped an alert into the delete function when I noticed the one I was clicking was not the one being removed.  The alert always showed an index of 2.  You are passing in $index, which says to me it should be the table index of the row in which the button is pressed.  But it's always 2.  WHat am I missing in my understanding?

Comment: Yes you are right,index must point to the row that we intended to delete. Please have a look at the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CC5FZBRPKZnox7831Fqd?p=preview) demo, hope this answers your query :)